# How can I unfold all in qtcreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

In `qtcreator` there is a way to fold all by doing `Edit>Advanced>Toggle Fold all` but I cannot find how to do the opposite.

How can I unfold all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Toggle Fold All` (inside the `Edit` menu at the top go to `Advanced`, this setting is the last of the third group of settings) unfolds all if all is folded (at least it is supposed to, and does so here)

Comment: Doesn't actually work in Qt Creator 5.0.2. I have some sections folded. Hitting "Toggle Fold All" folds everything, hitting it again restores to what was folded before.

Comment: Seems to work here (Qt Creator 7), unfolds all after it folded everything.

Comment: Works in QT Creator 12.  Although ChatGPT 4 is unaware of this.